# Problems with EditText and soft keyboard in a fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm currently building an android application that enables users to take pictures and write details of it. The application uses Sherlock libraries.

I've implemented a SherlockFragment to display the image and a few EditText and TextView to enable users to key in information of the image. However, when one of the EditText is on focus, all the fields are pushed up and the soft keyboard pops up.

Here is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dip"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
        android:contentDescription="desc" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Title:"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editTextSimple" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
        android:textSize="15sp"/>

     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextSimple"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dip">
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Description:"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editTextSimple1" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
        android:textSize="15sp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextSimple1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"  
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dip">
    </EditText>

    <Button android:textColor="#FF000000" 
        android:id="@+id/submitButton" 
        android:text="@string/memorySubmit" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dip"
        android:onClick = "submit"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

From what I understand, in an activity, one have to place this `<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="...." >` in the Android Manifest to adjust the view when the soft keyboard is called upon. However, how do we set this for fragments?

Answer (score 61):

this worked for me in a scenario where I was using multiple layouts and a viewstub to create a messaging screen. Place this in onCreate() Hope this helps.

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Comment: worked for me and saved my day.adding a comment so that others might know this works.

Comment: @ kenodoggy this is worked for me while open first time, but when i click  and start to enter the text then my layout is again push up. how to solve this? pls let me know if you know.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Working perfectly from a fragment

Comment: that's working in fragment, but i wonder does is sets the input mode value as permanent or just for the fragment lifecycle?

how can i go back to the previous \ default value after i leave the fragment?

Answer (score 12):

All fragments of one `Activity` have the same behaviour as their parent `Activity`, but if you need different keyboard behaviour for different `Fragments`, you could dynamically change this property from your `Fragment` code like this:

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.softInputMode.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Evos! Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, it is still not working. I think the problem might be because of the `android:layout_above`, though I can't be too sure about it.

Comment: Have you try to set different variation of this param in you manifest?

Comment: I did. I realized that the problem lies with the layout itself and not the soft keyboard. So I've implemented a scroll view and it works! Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 9):

This can be used in Fragment Class to move the Edit text up and Scroll till end.

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Answer (score 8):

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

All the Fragments related to that activity behave same, if you want to change the behaviour of perticular fragment than use the following one

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this `getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);`

Comment: Seems like a repeat of [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17581892).

Answer (score 2):

I have also this issue occur in my project, I have developed my project using fragments and tabs,

If we take relative layout and keep above and below dependency and at last button with

> android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

then it will make issue, The Solution is take the ScrollView inside root Linear or Relative Layout and inside ScrollView take one child view as Linear or Relative and set all the view below each other in RelativeLayout (if taken Relative in child view) or no need to set dependency in Linear.

That's it, It will work... :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Fragment** then use

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

and if you are using **DialogFragment** then use this one

```
getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   android:launchMode="singleTask"
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

this change in manifest works fine for me

Comment: This will work for Activity but he is looking for how user fragments.....