# Scrolling doesn't work in fragments tabs

Tags: android, scroll

I am currently developing an app for my class where the user can store his marks in every exam what they have scored. In-app there are 6 subjects and for each subject 2 assignments when the user typing the marks in edittext with the keyboard the fragment is not scrolling

I am trying to add scroller when the screen size is not enough and also when the user is entering text in EditText by having the keyboard in fragments.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:fillViewport="true">


    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        tools:context="com.nec.neccalc.FirstFragment">

            TextView and EditText will write here

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

[Image of the fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHE04.jpg)

I went through many questions with the same question I have asked because not any answer helped me. I gone through [Problems with EditText and soft keyboard in a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037915/problems-with-edittext-and-soft-keyboard-in-a-fragment) and added `getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);`  in the onCreate and also tried in onCreateView in fragment but it doesn't help

I have checked by adding `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` .

10sec Video Link how the my app is and where the scroller is not working [Video](https://www.youtube.com/upload?redirect_to_classic=true).

My Complete Project [Download Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1De15MxzXSNLGhFRipDYyESdxU956tM_y)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly just add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan` in the Manifest on the Activity holding the Fragment:

```
<activity
   android:name=".MyBeautifulActivity"
   android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan" />
```

### EDIT

So, remove  **everywhere**:

`getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);`

Then add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize` (see documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)) in your Manifest (like above). Use `adjustResize` not `adjustPan`

Comment: Thank you for replying me I have already added but it doesn't make any change. After adding it before I came to know WindowsSoftInputMode is only when we want to scroll activity, not fragment.

Comment: I tried with your project (btw you don't need to share the build folders and the folders starting with a ".") so it should work

Comment: I have removed all `getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);` and added  `<activity android:name=".MarksEntryActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>` to manifest file, but it has not worked. Please check whether I have done it incorrect way or not. I am very new to programming. Thank you for commenting back.

Comment: Ok. I don't have access to a computer with AS until tomorrow. I'll let you know.

Comment: You need to add `android:measureAllChildren="true"` on the ScrollView in `fragment_first.xml`. Try and let me know

Comment: Thanks for remembering and commenting back and spending the time to help others.I have added it to the ScrollView but it doesn't make any change.  I have attached the project https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Ut5pb2AxMHb50Cg10PumsmJzP1A7heLy you may get the clear view on it.

Comment: On ALL your Toolbar remove `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"`. And search for `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN` in your entire project (CTRL+SHIFT+F on Windows) to remove all of them (as already mentioned).

Comment: If you want the keyboard to not be automatically displayed when the screen is displayed, you can add `stateAlwaysHidden` together with `adjustResize` (`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize" `)

Comment: Yes, it's working fine.To be honest I spend many hours on this issue before asking the question.  Thank you for solving my problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have uploaded the APP in to play store, have a glance.   [NEC Calc](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nec.surneccalc&hl=en)